# Advanced search complete event not firing in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, events, advanced-search

As the title suggests I cannot get the advanced search complete event to fire. I am running VBA through Excel 2013. I have a sub running in worksheet1 which creates a test object which then runs an advanced search. This is all working fine, and the search object does return results. However, the advanced search complete event never fires. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**Main code:**

```
Sub testing()

Dim test As Class1
Set test = New Class1

Call test.TestAdvancedSearchComplete

End Sub
```

**Class 1:**

```
Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean
Dim sch As Outlook.search
Dim rsts As Outlook.Results



Private Sub myOlApp_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As search)
    MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired."
    blnSearchComp = True
End Sub



Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete()
Dim i As Integer

blnSearchComp = False
Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'"
Const strS As String = "Inbox"

Set sch = myOlApp.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF, False, “Test”)

While blnSearchComp = False
    DoEvents
Wend

Set rsts = sch.Results
For i = 1 To rsts.Count
    Debug.Print rsts.Item(i).SenderName
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses! I have changed both of these things and am still having a problem.

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses! I have changed both of these things and am still having a problem. Pradeep, it seems changing the application declaration as you suggested kicked up an error 91 "object variable or with block variable not set" on the execution of the search which was not there before. This might be due to the fact you can't have keyword new in application declaration? Also, Just changing the procedure name as CBRF23 suggested still isn't firing the event either.

Comment: On which line do you get that error?

Comment: It was on Set sch = myOlApp.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF, False, "Test"). It was generated because I didn't declare "set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application" when I changed "Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application" to "Dim WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application" since it wouldn't let me keep the "New" word in there (said it was an invalid keyword or something.   So now everything is executing, the advanced search is working, but the event still hasn't fired.

Comment: This just means that your `set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application` line is not being called. Put a breakpoint on that line to verify and check what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I added that line into the code it was fine and the search would run and even return results, however the search complete event still never fires.

Comment: Pradeep, this solved the problem. Thank you very much for the extended help. I had changed the private sub's name as CBRF23 suggested, but I don't think he realized I was running out of excel not outlook.

Comment: I had deleted that comment thinking that it would be absurd to think otherwise from the code you posted here. Glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow raising events you need to declare your objects with `WithEvents`

```
Dim WithEvents myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
```

Comment: Would the application declaration be the only declaration that needs the "WithEvents" label?

Comment: Any object whose events you want to handle would need that `WithEvents` in the declaration.

Comment: On a side note, I would also advise you to remove the `New` keyword from declaration and initialize it separately. Declare as `Dim WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application` and in new/initialize method `Set myOlApp = New Outlook.Application`. However this has nothing to do with the problem you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The *AdvancedSearchComplete event* has a special procedure name which the compiler needs to see in order to tie your code to the event.   Change the procedure name to:

```
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search)
```